# Can an action verb have an adverb of degree?

Tags: adverbs

Wondering why “very,” “so” or “too” are not used with a verb, I think an action verb cannot have an adverb of degree, but “it hurts too much” makes me think again. Can an action verb take an adverb of degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an adverb of degree with a verb! But not every adverb would be idiomatic. We usually use "very" with adjectives, not verbs.

Using your example, you could say:

- My hand *really* hurts.

Or, alternatively, you could say:

- My hand is really hurting
- My hand hurts very much

You could use 'very' if you changed the verb 'hurts' for an adjective:

- My hand is very painful

Answer (score 0):

In

> It hurts *too* *much*.

the adverb of degree ***much*** modifies the verb *hurt*, whereas the adverb of degree ***too*** modifies *much*.

*Very* and *too* can only modify adverbs or adjectives, and you can determine that if you try to use them alone with the verb:

> *It hurts too. [This sentence would only work id *too* had the meaning of "also", not that of an adverb of degree, meaning "more than enough"]

or

> *It hurts very.

About ***very***, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/very) says that

> we use very **before adverbs and adjectives** to add emphasis. It means ‘to a great degree’

and it goes on to explain other limitations of use.

As for ***too***, it says that

> we use *too* immediately before adjectives and adverbs (no mention of verbs):
>
> - This coffee is ***too** sweet*.
>
> Too before adjective/adverb + to-infinitive
>
> - The water was ***too** cold to swim* in. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/too))

I don't speak many foreign languages, but in the ones I do, both *very* and *too* cannot stand on their own next to a verb as adverbs of degree, so I am not sure this is a use specific only to English.

However, there are other adverbs of degree that can modify verbs:

> I ***barely*** know him/ I ***barely*** touched him.
> She ***quite*** enjoyed the book.
> You missed them ***terribly/awfully***.

And the examples can go on. This [site](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/adverbs-degree/) has helpful explanations. It says:

> Adverbs of degree tell us about the *intensity* of something. *Adverbs of degree are usually placed before the adjective, adverb, or **verb*** that they modify, although there are some *exceptions*.